# Subsetting data in R for repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. df1 = 300000rows df2 = 100000rows. Few values in df1 are repeated (can be seen from dimension of data) as I have to a graphical analysis on data. The df2 contains metadata for values in rows in df2.

```
dput(df1[1:5, ])
c("ENSG00000272905.1", "ENSG00000269148.1", "ENSG00000272905.1", 
"ENSG00000204581.2", "ENSG00000158486.12")

dput(df2[1:5, ])
structure(list(ensembl_gene_id = c("ENSG00000004838", "ENSG00000005206", 
"ENSG00000007174", "ENSG00000009724", "ENSG00000009844"), hgnc_symbol = c("ZMYND10", 
"SPPL2B", "DNAH9", "MASP2", "VTA1"), gene_biotype = c("protein_coding", 
"protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to match each rows in df1 and store its metadata (given in df2) in corresponding columns. My expected results are:

```
    dput(df3[1:5, ])
c("ENSG00000000419.11 ENSG00000000419     DPM1       protein_cod", 
"ENSG00000000419.11 ENSG00000000419     DPM1       protein_cod", 
"ENSG00000000460.15 ENSG00000000460     C1orf112   protein_cod", 
"ENSG00000000460.15 ENSG00000000460     C1orf112   protein_cod", 
"ENSG00000000460.15 ENSG00000000460     C1orf112   protein_cod"
)
```

I tried `match` function but it returned `NA` as values in column1 of df1 are in decimals. I also tried `%in%` operator, but that returned "`Error:incorrect dimension`".
What should script look like where I can subset my data without omitting repeated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- result <- df1 %>%
  mutate(ensembl_gene_id = sub('\\..*', '', ensembl_gene_id)) %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'ensembl_gene_id')

result
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but your script returned error: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: @imaparna It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I have tried to reproduce sample of my data in the question above, please have a look and let me know for any further requirements

Comment: I see that you have values like `"ENSG00000272905.1"` in `df1` but there are no dots in `df2$ensembl_gene_id` Do you need to compare the values in `ensembl_gene_id` after removing the dots ? See the updated answer if that helps.

Comment: I see your updated script has worked, However I couldn't understand what caused change in my data-set dimension. dim(df1) = 348698 ; dim(df2) = 124797 ; dim(result) = 17360540?

Comment: That must be because you might have duplicate `ensembl_gene_id` in either `df1` or `df2` or both. Try adding `%>% distinct(ensembl_gene_id, .keep_all = TRUE)` after the `inner_join` code to keep only the unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

R automatically joins the dataframes by common variable names, but you would most likely want to specify `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ensembl_gene_id")` to make sure that you are matching on only the fields you desired.

Comment: as mentioned in question, merge function also returned zero values because first column in df1 is in decimals.

Comment: there is no mention of merge not giving correct results in your question. if that's the case, then you can coerce the data in that column into characters using as.character()

Comment: Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced. So, I tried as.numeric() too, it didn't work even.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always a fan of the dplyr package (part of the tidyverse).
You will likely need something like this

Unique drops duplicates

```
df3 <- inner_join(unique(df1), df2, on = "ensembl_gene_id")
```

Alternatively you could just filter for the desired columns

```
df3 <- df2 %>% filter(ensembl_gene_id %in% pull(df1, ensembl_gene_id))
```

Edit: just reread the question, ignore `unique`. Also the second method will drop uniques too.

You just want `df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, on = "ensembl_gene_id")`

Comment: This also returned zero values